# security: java embedded in webbrowser and pure Php website: is there a difference?

Tags: java, php, security

A friend of mine just told me this:

For security in a webbrowser, there's only Java or Flash.

I really strongly doubt that, and I'm pretty sur that there's no difference between a Website (properly written) in Php and a Java app embedded in a Webbrower.

Is he right, and if so, what are the main differences (*only* from a security point of view, don't start talking about memory consumption and son on, please...)?

Comment: What kind of security are we talking about here? Generally, *everything* client-side is insecure, period.

Comment: So your answer is like "what you ask is stupid: everything client-side is insecure, period"?

Comment: No, that was a question. What sort of security? There is a world of difference between "Protecting the financial data of a user while letting them see and edit it" and "Preventing a user from editing data on your server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Deceze has this pretty correct:

Everything client side must be considered insecure, as an attacker has access to it (anything an attacker has should be considered insecure and compromised)

At least on the server side you can lock things down, because there is code the attacker can't get at (assuming security controls are correct), whereas an attacker has access to all the client side code, encryption keys etc. Even obfuscation just slows attackers down, it shouldn't be considered real security.

Simple answer - just don't do it: everything client side is insecure!

Answer (score 0):

So I think he meant Javascript, because I can surely write applications in C and use HTML/CSS .  Anything that you do not control, client side code (mobile code), is not secure.  Primarily because you have given all of the control to the attacker.  This video:  [Joseph Mccray](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJsNu0VRKYY) may help to show some of the ways people attack systems, it is NSFW (for language), but it is entertaining.  It is a DEFCON presentation.

If you want there to be security in your application you must use a defense in depth mindset.  Any "validations" you do on the client side must be repeated on the server, for the reasons illustrated in the video and my prior explanation.  To summarize your friend is incorrect.

Comment: He didn't mean JavaScript: he meant a Java applet, launched in a webbrowser.

Comment: @OlivierPons ah that answers that :)